# amazon emr spark submission from S3 not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a cluster up and running. I am trying to add a step to run my code. The code itself works fine on a single instance. Only thing is I can't get it to work off S3.

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXX --steps Type=spark,Name=SomeSparkApp,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--executor-memory,0.5g,s3://<mybucketname>/mypythonfile.py]
```

This is exactly what examples show I should do. What am I doing wrong?

Error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown/unsupported param List(--executor-memory, 0.5g, --executor-cores, 2, --primary-py-file, s3://<mybucketname>/mypythonfile.py, --class, org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner)

Usage: org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client [options]
Options:
  --jar JAR_PATH           Path to your application's JAR file (required in yarn-cluster
                           mode)
    .
    .
    .
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

When I specify as this instead:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXX --steps Type=spark,Name= SomeSparkApp,Args=[--executor-memory,0.5g,s3://<mybucketname>/mypythonfile.py]
```

I get this error instead:

```
Error: Only local python files are supported: Parsed arguments:
  master                  yarn-client
  deployMode              client
  executorMemory          0.5g
  executorCores           2
```

EDIT: IT gets further along when I manually create the python file after SSH'ing into the cluster, and specifying as follows:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id 'j-XXXXX' --steps Type=spark,Name= SomeSparkApp,Args=[--executor-memory,1g,/home/hadoop/mypythonfile.py]
```

But, not doing the job.

Any help appreciated. This is really frustrating as a well documented method on AWS's own blog here https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx578UTQUV7LRP/Submitting-User-Applications-with-spark-submit does not work.

Comment: does your EMR cluster have the proper IAM permissions to access `S3`?

Comment: Yes, as I can do bootstrap actions just fine from S3. That part succeeds. BTW - when I use the GUI, it worked. Really frustrated now. :)

Comment: DId you ever figure this out? We are running into the same issue. If I use a jar from the local FS it works. I pass in one via S3 and it fails.

Comment: I did...I wish I had the exact commands I used. Unfortunately, I don't have access to them right now. I believe I submitted like this: `Args=["spark-submit",s3://blah-blah/blah.py,......]`.

Answer (score 2):

I will ask, just in case, you used your correct buckets and cluster ID-s?

But anyways, I had similar problems, like I could not use `--deploy-mode,cluster` when reading from S3. 
When I used `--deploy-mode,client,--master,local[4]` in the arguments, then I think it worked. But I think I still needed something different, can't remember exactly, but I resorted to a solution like this:

Firstly, I use a bootstrap action where a shell script runs the command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<mybucket>/wordcount.py wordcount.py
```

and then I add a step to the cluster creation through the SDK in my Go application, but I can recollect this info and give you the CLI command like this:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXX --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name="Spark Program",Jar="command-runner.jar",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=["spark-submit",--master,local[4],/home/hadoop/wordcount.py,s3://<mybucket>/<inputfile.txt> s3://<mybucket>/<outputFolder>/]
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for days and finally discovered [this thread](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201501.mbox/%3CCAFbGCAh=7sPC4PR-n6iuVRbMpy_M7bQLDgU4-3cpfp-zbgxPHQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) which states

> PySpark currently only supports local
>   files. This does not mean it only runs in local mode, however; you can
>   still run PySpark on any cluster manager (though only in client mode). All
>   this means is that your python files must be on your local file system.
>   Until this is supported, the straightforward workaround then is to just
>   copy the files to your local machine.